# Create a list of integer up to a specified value in Ansible 2.2

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I want to create a variable containing an integer list using the maximum value of the list as input.

For example:

```
max: 5 # Maximum of my list
```

Expected result:

```
list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # the list
```

My purpose is to use this in a Jinja2 template (maybe there is a way to do it directly in the template):

```
{% for ind in list %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jinja2 [`range`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#range):

```
{% for n in range(1, max+1) %}
{{ n }}
{% endfor %}
```

Mind the remark: "*The end point is omitted!*", so you need to specify `max+1`.

Comment: Working well ! Thank you.